# Nested array in JSON to different rows in CSV

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "transmitterId": "30451155eda2",
  "rssiSignature": [
    {
      "receiverId": "001bc509408201d5",
      "receiverIdType": 1,
      "rssi": -52,
      "numberOfDecodings": 5,
      "rssiSum": -52
    },
    {
      "receiverId": "001bc50940820228",
      "receiverIdType": 1,
      "rssi": -85,
      "numberOfDecodings": 5,
      "rssiSum": -85
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1574228579837
}
```

I want to convert it to CSV format, where each row corresponds to an entry in `rssiSignature` (I have added the header row for visualization purposes):

```
timestamp,transmitterId,receiverId,rssi
1574228579837,"30451155eda2","001bc509408201d5",-52
1574228579837,"30451155eda2","001bc50940820228",-85
```

My current attempt is the following, but I get a single CSV row:

```
$ jq -r '[.timestamp, .transmitterId, .rssiSignature[].receiverId, .rssiSignature[].rssi] | @csv' test.jsonl
1574228579837,"30451155eda2","001bc509408201d5","001bc50940820228",-52,-85
```

How can I use jq to generate different rows for each entry of the `rssiSignature` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reuse a value of the upper level, like the `timestamp`, for every item of the `rssiSignature` array, you can define it as a variable. You can get your csv like this:

```sh
jq -r '.timestamp as $t | .transmitterId as $tid |
       .rssiSignature[] | [ $t, $tid, .receiverId, .rssi] | @csv
      ' file.json
```

Output:

```
1574228579837,"30451155eda2","001bc509408201d5",-52
1574228579837,"30451155eda2","001bc50940820228",-85
```

---

Also here is an way to print headers for an output file in `bash`, independent of what commands we call, using [commands grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

```sh
(
printf "timestamp,transmitterId,receiverId,rssi\n"
jq -r '.timestamp as $t | .transmitterId as $tid |
       .rssiSignature[] | [ $t, $tid, .receiverId, .rssi] | @csv
      ' file.json
) > output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the task can be accomplished without the use of any variables; one can also coax jq to include a header:

```
jq -r '
  ["timestamp","transmitterId","receiverId","rssi"],
   [.timestamp, .transmitterId] + (.rssiSignature[] | [.receiverId,.rssi])
  | @csv'
```

#### A single header with multiple files

One way to produce a single header with multiple input files would be to use `inputs` in conjunction with the `-n` command-line option. This happens also to be efficient:

```
jq -nr '
["timestamp","transmitterId","receiverId","rssi"],
 (inputs |
  [.timestamp, .transmitterId] + (.rssiSignature[] | [.receiverId,.rssi]))
| @csv'
```

Comment: @kmundnic  I 'd use this, also prints the headers easily. In case you had some longer paths until your array, I guess it would be better to define variables.

Comment: @thanasisp I tested both answers and yours is slightly faster for my use case (reading huge JSONL files and translating them to CSV files).  I have ~300 files with up to 21M rows each, so time matters :-)

Comment: @peak is there a way using jq to preprend the header only once if I am reading several  JSONL instead of a single JSON from a file? I can do this in bash, just wondering if there's an option in jq.

Comment: kmundnic - See update.  @thanasisp - Tx for attending to the `-n` bug.